# What to do when exploratory factor analysis results are different for complete-cases and imputed data?

Tags: factor-analysis, data-imputation, exploratory-data-analysis

I have a hundred items that I'm performing EFA on, with around 370 complete cases. Using parallel analysis to determine the number of factors to extract, EFA gave 9 factors, all of which make theoretical sense.

However, I have 280 incomplete cases, which are missing answers for up to 10% of the items. Missing data is not at random, with a couple of items missing responses for 20-40% of all respondents. Using the `R` package `missForest`, I imputed the missing data and performed factor analysis on the resulting imputed dataset. This gave me 10 factors, around 5 of which are the same as the previous analysis and 5 'new' factors.

What is the protocol when the results of imputed data analysis are different to those of a complete cases analysis? Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: There are questions for you that are not so far about imputation. Are you doing 280+1 FAs? Why so much, what is the goal of your your study? Please tell more about it in your question. What are gross and listwise $n$s in your incompele datasets?

Comment: All the answers to your questions are in the text above, I think you may have mis-read it.

I am doing 2 FAs; one with complete-cases data  (i.e. list wise deletion; 370 cases have complete data) and one with imputed data (370 cases have complete data, 280 have some imputed data for a total of 650 cases). I don't know what you mean by 'gross n' in my incomplete datasets.

Comment: `I have 280 incomplete data sets` This is what bewilders. Please correct it then. Cases not "data sets".

Comment: Apologies, fixed.